# Integrate Moxtra Android SSO with SAML

Tags: android

Moxtra provides SAML SSO based authentication for web based apps by using the following javascript code:

```
type="text/javascript" src="https://www.moxtra.com/api/js/moxtra-latest.js" id="moxtrajs" data-client-id="CLIENT-ID" data-app-key="IDP-ENTITY-ID" data-org-id="ORG-ID"
```

However, how can I integrate an Android App to Moxtra using SSO SAML sign when using Android SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SAML bearer method to get the access token (https://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/docs-oauth/#saml-bearer) and use the access token with Moxtra's Android SDK.